# My login form returns invalid username/password even if it is correct

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm creating a simple user registration and login system. The registration works fine and it stores the users in DB. But when i try to login even if i get the username/password correct it still returns that It's not correct. I can't seem to find the problem here is the code. Login form:

```
<form method="post" action = 'plogin.php'>
            <h2 class="sr-only">Login Form</h2>
            <div class="illustration"><i class="icon ion-ios-navigate"></i></div>
            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Е-маил"></div>
            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Лозинка"></div>
            <div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Најава</button></div><a href="#" class="forgot">Ја заборавивте лозинката? Кликнете овде.</a></form>
```

Validation and checking if username and password exists:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!empty($_POST)) {
    include('includes/general.php');
    if(!$connection){
        die("Failed to connect to database ".mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['password']);
    $hashedPassword = hash('SHA256', $password);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die (mysqli_error($connection));
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        echo "<script>window.location.href = 'user.php';</script>";
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('invalid username/password');
            window.location.href= 'login.php';</script>";

    }
} else {
    echo "<script>window.location.href = 'index.php';</script>";
}
```

Comment: Try removing the hash and check if it works.
`$hashedPassword = $password;`

Comment: `$_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array($result);` what are you trying to do here?

Comment: @emix `hash` will return the same value every time. That is using sha256, it is not `password_hash`. https://3v4l.org/Wshlu

Answer (score -1):

You've mixed your variables.
I guess your password is stored as hash, but you're comparing it to the unhashed value.

try instead

```
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['password']);
$hashedPassword = hash('SHA256', $password);
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$hashedPassword'";
```

Even though I wonder why you try to put the full result into $_SESSION. I wouldn't do that, if you need to have some values in your session (e.g. userId, email and username or similiar) I would just store those instead of all columns from the row. Also doing a query without specification of columns you want to retrieve is not best practice, see this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-is-the-reason-not-to-use-select) for explaination.

You maybe want to check PHP-reference for [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to improve your concept.

Comment: I don't get why my answer received a downvote. Please explain so I can understand what's the issue with my answer.

Answer (score -2):

did you mean

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$hashedDassword'";
```

?

and also, I Highly advise AGAINST writing your own registration and sign up form, unless this is for an exercise.

Comment: It's for an exercise

Comment: good to hear. so you actually meant to query with the password and not the hashed password?

Comment: Yes that was my initial thought. But it didin't work so Im asking for help.

Comment: I don't understand. Did you try querying the database for the hashed password instead of the password and it didn't work? why do you have this line  $hashedPassword = hash('SHA256', $password);

Answer (score -3):

Hey don't use single quote  for PHP variables use string con cat (.) operator

`$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '".$email."' AND password = '".$password."'";`

Comment: both `'$var'` and `'".$var."'` do the same thing.